# Как читать из файла, игнорируя пробелы и перенос строки

Tags: java

У меня есть txt файл, в нем значения:
6 6
1
Как прочитать из файла эти значения и записать их в переменные? Не получается прочитать "1", потому что она идет после переноса строки

Comment: А чем вы читаете Файл?  надеюсь  reader'ом,

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас текстовый файл содержит только несколько целых чисел, достаточно использовать `Scanner` и его методы `hasNextInt` / `nextInt`, так как они нечувствительны к переносам строки в качестве разделителей:

```java
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("mydata.txt"))) {
    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Прочитанные переменные можно добавлять в список, массив, и т.д.